# Format date column then ORDER BY in MSSQL query

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

I am calling an "Invoice Date" field from the database and later in my ColdFusion I format that date as follows:

```
#DateFormat(SESSION.ClientListInvoice.InvoicedDate,"MM/DD/YYYY")#
```

But I actually need to format that column before I use the ORDER DESC/ASC in my original query. Below is what I am trying to accomplish:

```
<CFQUERY NAME="Get_ClientInvoice" DATASOURCE="#this.DSN#">
    SELECT CI.ClientName,CI.InvoicedDate
FROM ClientInvoices
WHERE Blah Blah Blah
ORDER BY FORMAT("mm/dd/yyyy", CI.InvoicedDate) DESC, CI.ClientName ASC
</CFQUERY>
```

I am just not sure how to format the date from within the query.

Comment: Formatting is commonly used when data is displayed not while `Ordering`

Comment: Which version of `SQL Server` you are using

Comment: Why do you need to format it before ordering? You can use ORDER BY CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR,InvoicedDate,101) AS DATE) DESC, but as others have already asked, it does depend on which version of SQL Server is being used. ORDER BY CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CI.InvoicedDate,101) AS DATETIME) DESC should work for ordering.

Comment: 10.0.5500.0 SP3 Standard Edition (64-bit)  I hope that helps with the version question.

Comment: I mean SQL Server 2008, SQL Server 2012, SQL Server 2014

Comment: The reason I am formatting it before ordering is the time stamp when I show it to the page will look the same since I am only showing month day year. I then want to order by the Client Name for entries that have the same month/day/year. But when I ORDER BY on the date as is they will never be the same value so I can then sort by the client name since there is more info then month/day/year. IF that makes sense.

Comment: Blah, I am off my game today. Type SELECT @@VERSION and print the results.

Comment: I should have know that too. Thanks: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP3) - 10.0.5500.0 (X64)   Sep 21 2011 22:45:45   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: )

Comment: SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,CAST(CI.InvoicedDate AS DATE),101) ... ORDER BY CAST(CI.InvoicedDate AS DATE) DESC

Comment: You realize that the ordering format you chose means that your records will not be sorted in reverse chronological order, right?

Comment: @Denoteone - You should not need to preformat the result column unless you are grouping the results somehow. Sounds like simply ordering the results by CAST(CI.InvoicedDate AS DATE) DESC should suffice (as others have said).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your needs, since you are using SQL Server 2008, you can add formatting in the SELECT statement itself and the ORDER BY. If you simply want to order it effectively, you just need the ORDER BY portion. But if you also want to format the display of the records, you need to include the formatting in the SELECT statement itself:

```
SELECT CI.ClientName,CONVERT(VARCHAR,CAST(CI.InvoicedDate AS DATE),101) AS InvoicedDate
FROM ClientInvoices AS CI
WHERE Blah Blah Blah
ORDER BY CAST(CI.InvoicedDate AS DATE) DESC, CI.ClientName ASC
```

Also, you didn't alias your table name in the query, so "CI." prefacing your columns would have caused an error.

Comment: Thank you sir. I actually only used the ORDER BY part but it is work as it should now. Thanks! +1 checked.